# datagrid.validationrules error

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hello I would like you to help me find my issue:

I am working with two datagrids, one of then has been binded to a datatable and the other one to its childrows with a datarelation. My problem is when I am trying to validate the date just looking if the row has errors.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid2" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid1, Path=SelectedItem.myDataRelation}">
     <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
         <validation:ValidationRules ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
     </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
</DataGrid>
```

And my ValidationRules is defined as:

```
public class ValidationRules : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        BindingGroup group = (BindingGroup)value;
        StringBuilder error = null;
        foreach (var item in group.Items)
        {
            DataRowView rowView = item as DataRowView;
            if (rowView != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rowView.Row.RowError))
                {
                    if (error == null)
                        error = new StringBuilder();
                    error.Append((error.Length != 0 ? ", " : "") + rowView.Row.RowError);
                }
            }
        }
        if (error != null)
            return new ValidationResult(false, error.ToString());
        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

When I choose an item in myDataGrid1 and edit a row in myDataGrid2 and this is in error then when I choose another item and then comeback to the item in with has the error in myDataGrid1 according with myDataGrid2 the aplications throw me:

```
"DeferRefresh is not allowed during an addNew or EditItem transaction.: 
 An unhandled exception ocurred, and the application is terminating".
```

Does anybody know what I should do ??

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wpf/thread/482a9695-89e1-414c-8828-3b66f47afbdc, this might be a bug in the data grid.